# clickable symbols to insert

Tags: javascript, text-editor, symbols

I have a site where users can type posts.  I want to add an some simple buttons on the side of the site that insert different symbols.  The symbols dont need to be crazy like the windings font but just some basic math symbols.  Also, how could I add the ability to highlight and make a selection a subscript (like Microsoft word)?  Thanks.

Comment: What language/framework are you using to generate html?

Comment: @agent sorry im a complete noob.  I didnt know I was generating HTML.  I thought i just wrote it.  Id like to use javascript if that's possible?

Comment: It's possible, in fact it's the only solution (unless you want to do it in flash :>)

Comment: Well, if you want users to be able to post their formulas to the server, you'll need something on the server to save their stuff somewhere.

Comment: @agent do you mean a mysql database? I can use those.  How can I use javascript to insert symbols in a textarea?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) for your textarea. They both allow users to input custom characters (Look for the Ω - Omega symbol on the toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

Those options @Thomas Li suggested are pretty neat.  If they are more advanced than you want, here's a post with a [similar question](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4686.htm).

If you're asking for suggestions...  I like the way TinyMCE launched that little window to let you select a symbol, but if you want just a small amount of characters, you could probably just list those as a toolbutton bar above the text, like stack overflow's formatting bar above "Your Answer".